# How to write SQL running total with multiple conditions for one partition group?

Tags: sql, sum, window, teradata

I have a table with account balances of debtors. I am trying to calculate the number of months debtor have negative balance up to particular date (see Desired output), but it is not working.

How is it possible to start counting again from zero, but for the same group, because it is possible that customer will have a debtor status a few times during the same year (negative balance)?

```
Id      Date_Valid  Balance Desired_Output
------------------------------------------
4001    2022-01-12  -4500   3
4001    2022-01-11  -3200   2
4001    2022-01-10   -800   1
4001    2022-01-09    800   
4001    2022-01-08   2400   
4001    2022-01-07   3300   
4001    2022-01-06   5000   
4001    2022-01-05   4000   
4001    2022-01-04   2100   
4001    2022-01-03    900   
4001    2022-01-02    100   
4001    2022-01-01   -900   1
4002    2022-01-12   1900   
4002    2022-01-11   1400   
4002    2022-01-10    800   
4002    2022-01-09    400   
4002    2022-01-08  -1400   2
4002    2022-01-07  -3200   1
4002    2022-01-06    200   
4002    2022-01-05  -1500   4
4002    2022-01-04  -4000   3
4002    2022-01-03  -7800   2
4002    2022-01-02  -6500   1
4002    2022-01-01    500
```

Here a SQL sample code

```
CREATE TABLE Balance (
    Client_Id INT,
    Date_Valid DATETIME,
    Balance INT
);

INSERT INTO Balance (Client_Id, Date_Valid, Balance, Desired_Output)
VALUES 
    (4001, '2022-01-12', -4500, 3),
    (4001, '2022-01-11', -3200, 2),
    (4001, '2022-01-10', -800, 1),
    (4001, '2022-01-09', 800, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-08', 2400, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-07', 3300, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-06', 5000, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-05', 4000, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-04', 2100, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-03', 900, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-02', 100, NULL),
    (4001, '2022-01-01', -900, 1),
    (4002, '2022-01-12', 1900, NULL),
    (4002, '2022-01-11', 1400, NULL),
    (4002, '2022-01-10', 800, NULL),
    (4002, '2022-01-09', 400, NULL),
    (4002, '2022-01-08', -1400, 2),
    (4002, '2022-01-07', -3200, 1),
    (4002, '2022-01-06', 200, NULL),
    (4002, '2022-01-05', -1500, 4),
    (4002, '2022-01-04', -4000, 3),
    (4002, '2022-01-03', -7800, 2),
    (4002, '2022-01-02', -6500, 1),
    (4002, '2022-01-01', 500, NULL);
```

Comment: Your date format is confusing, YDM, and there's no DATETIME in Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can also use Teradata's `RESET WHEN` clause:

```
select b.*, SUM(case when Balance < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   OVER (partition by Client_ID order by Date_Valid
   RESET WHEN Balance >= 0 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as Desired_Output
from Balance b
order by Client_ID, Date_Valid DESC;
```

The SUM will reset to zero; if you want NULL then add `ZeroIfNull` function around the cumulative SUM.